# 2D Array as a Class Variable

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I am not able to understand why I have to mention the data type of the 2d array again and again if declared it as a class variable:

```
public class DDR
{
    int[][] arr; 
    int m;
    int n;
    public DDR() {
        m=0;
        n=0;
        int arr[][] = new int[m][n];
    }
}
```

When I omit `int`, it says "it's not a statement."

Comment: You are declaring variable twice that's why. To assign something you just need name of variable such as `arr = new int [m][n];` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, `arr` in the constructor is *not* a class variable, but rather a local variable that is shadowing the class variable. Both `int` and `[][]` are part of the type.

To initialize the class variable, don't declare a new variable. You must omit both the element type (`int`) and the array portion of the declaration (`[][]`). Also, `m` and `n` have default values of zero, so you may want to set them *before* allocating the arrays:

```
m = 1;
n = 1;
arr = new int[m][n];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `int arr [] []` phrase in your constructor is actually declaring a new array that shadows your field. Remember that arrays are variables, too. Omitting the `int` makes a statement that syntactically makes no sense. In this case, what you want is to assign an array to your field `arr` of type `int[][]`.

```
arr = new int[m][n];
```

Comment: Actually, class variables have default values assigned to them, so using them is ok, if you know what you're doing